# "Only the masochist would choose to study Russian" or "Only a masochist would choose to study Russian"? (use of articles in generic noun phrases)

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

From *[English is not Normal](https://aeon.co/essays/why-is-english-so-weirdly-different-from-other-languages)*, by John McWhorter:

> If someone were told he had a year to get as good at either Russian or Hebrew as possible, and would lose a fingernail for every mistake he made during a three-minute test of his competence, only **the** masochist would choose Russian – unless he already happened to speak a language related to it.

Could we substitute **"a"** for **"the"** here? Both "**the** masochist" and "**a** masochist" are generic noun phrases.

> If someone were told he had a year to get as good at either Russian or Hebrew as possible, and would lose a fingernail for every mistake he made during a three-minute test of his competence, only **a** masochist would choose Russian – unless he already happened to speak a language related to it.

Would this be okay? If not, why?

Comment: And only the sadist would dream up such a test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm another native speaker who can attest that *a masochist* is fine here.

Since the sentence is not taking about any particular masochist, then I agree with you that it is taking about a generic masochist. So I have to turn to John Lawler's post [Re: A question about the generic use of...](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html), which succinctly explains the difference in generic noun phrases when you use *a* and *the*. I assume you've  read this page, probably several times.

*The masochist* is the definite generic, which refers to

> the Prototype of a species, roughly the image we associate with tiger...

and

*a masochist*

> refers to the Definition of a species, that is, those properties that are absolutely necessary for anything to be a member. It doesn't work as the subject of any predicate that isn't definitional. But with a definitional property, it's certainly true for any member.

Since the sentence would then assert what *any masochist* would do, then yes, using the indefinite generic is fine here. At least that's how I interpret my intuitive and unflinching assurance that *a masochist* is fine here.

By the way, I tried to create a tag *generic noun phrase* but it got shot down without any reason given. Since not even English speakers are taught what they are, I think it's an important and germane topic for this site. Maybe someone should do a metapost about it  but I feel like I did my part and really don't want to repeat my attempt.

Edit: okay, thanks for creating the tag.

Comment: Thank you! I had created the tag **[generic noun phrases](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generic-noun-phrases)** several days ago and I've just attached it to this question. I'm interested whether in your view **a masochist** would sound a bit more condescending, as Ricky says.

Comment: Since both *the masochist* and *a masochist* refer to generic masochistics and not to any actual person in heaven and earth, I don't think the idea of "condescension" has any part of this  usage. If we call an actual person *a masochist* that could be condescending. But if we call an actual person  *the masochist* we are now saying that he or she is the prototypical masochist. *Here comes John Smith. Behold the masochist.*

Comment: But Ricky's answers and comments often contain a lot of flippant or extraneous information that can confuse the learner. So he's not the prototypical ELL Answerer, and his remarks very often confuse learners. And I am pretty sure John McWhorter knows his stuff. I've listened to two or three lecture series by McWhorter and I've never found him offer any linguistic info that is off the mark. Not all linguists agree on everything though. Maybe @Ricky will use his more winding writings back at ELL, once his suspension from that site expires.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to ask -- do you think that **the** and **a** serve equally well here? Would you personally pick **a** over **the**? I understand that **the** is not erroneous in any case.

Comment: @CopperKettle See my [earlier comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75865/only-the-masochist-would-choose-to-study-russian-or-only-a-masochist-would-ch#comment146408_76002). There is not a "better" usage; it depends what you want to get across. *The* refers to the prototypical masochist. He is unique, because there can be only one prototype. *A* refers to any masochist. Referring to the prototypical masochist works very well.

Answer (score 7):

"The masochist" and "a masochist" mean two different things in this context.

***A*** masochist is simply a person who happens to be a masochist.

***The*** masochist is a type, not a person.

> "Is that your dog?"
>   "Yes."
>   "What kind of dog is he?"
>   "He's a German Shepherd."

But:

> "They tell me you specialize in dogs."
>   "That's true."
>   "Specifically?"
>   "The Lab, the Yorkie, and the German Shepherd."

That, in a nutshell, is it.

Comment: So we could use freely either **a** or **the** in the sentence by McWhorter?

Comment: @CopperKettle: Yes, but the former would sound more condescending.

Comment: +1 for the point about "*the* masochist is a *type*" and the succinct canine example.

Comment: "more condescending" - because it would be kind of "describing" a particular person, and "**the**" would be pointing more at a blurred abstract image, a type. I see.

Comment: @snailboat: There are numerous posts on this forum in dire need of editing. Would you please stop mutilating good ones? I beg you, sir. Pray desist. And roll it back.

Comment: Please use the answer box to post answers, not off-topic rambles and diatribes that don't even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @snailboat: The off-topic rambles and diatribes, as you call them, have so far garnered an upvote count of +6. However, if doing what you're doing turns you on, by all means, do continue. I won't ask you again. My opinion of you has changed dramatically, but trifles of that sort stand no chance of bothering you even slightly, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, **a** can be substituted for **the** with no loss in understanding, however there is a slightly different meaning between the two.

Both clearly refer to someone who enjoys having pain inflicted upon them. **A** masochist refers to that type of person in a general sense. They may be **more or less** a masochist. **The** implies a **higher degree** or more **extreme** level. Consider :

> Blue is **a** color in the rainbow.
>   Blue is **the** colour of choice.

The first means: blue is **one of several** colors in a rainbow.
The second sentence means: blue is **the top chosen** colour.

So the author is saying that if you want to be a **top** masochist (not to be confused with **top/bottom** usage) study Russian, since **the more extreme masochist** will probably have the enjoyable experience of getting their fingernails pulled out...
[NB: if one is a masochist and happened to be very good at learning languages, this exercise would be self-defeating]

Having studied Russian, I can attest that the language, people, and culture are actually quite lovely, and the fingernail treatment does sound more Russian than Hebrew in aesthetic.

Comment: It's an interesting answer, but I don't think *the* works that way.  (Unfortunately, explaining how it does work isn't really possible in the space of a comment and would require a competing answer!)

Comment: @snailboat: I don't mind. Am curious to find out what the competing answer is. Make with the answer, I mean, do please post the answer.