# Definite or indefinite article with "generic reader"

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

Let's imagine we are talking about readers in general. Some like "intellectual" books, some like detective novels:

> **The** intellectual perusing “Foucault's Pendulum” and **the** simpleton absorbed in a pulp detective novel – both would be surprised to know how similar they are.

Would the use of **the** be similar in meaning to the use of **a**:

> **An** intellectual perusing “Foucault's Pendulum” and **a** simpleton absorbed in a pulp detective novel – both would be surprised to know how similar they are.

We are not talking about any specific persons.

Would the version with **a** be more 'harsh' towards these readers, and the version with **the** more 'lenient'? The matter is, the text as a whole says that a reader's motives are often selfish, that he often seeks to see his own reflection in the work of fiction, and hence intellectuals and the simple folk are kind of on the same footing.

Comment: Similar and dissimilar. I'd say that **The** reflects the speaker's confidence in the assumption that it will be intellectual who is reading Foucault and the amateur who is reading the pulp novel.  **The** makes the "typecasting" explicit.

Comment: Beyond referring to them as predictable types, there is nothing in the choice of article **The** which expresses any sort of harshness or leniency towards the two; there's no implication of "selfishness" .  BTW, **intellectual** and **amateur** are not opposites in the way that **professional** and **amateur** are.  There are amateur intellectuals and intellectual amateurs.  :)

Comment: Except that "types", in not seeing beyond their typicality, or not recognizing their typicality, can be said to be solipsistic ("see his own reflection in the work of fiction").

Comment: @TRomano - I've put *simpleton* in place of *amateur* to make them more distinct.

Comment: Plenty of simpleton intellectuals, IMO.  Simpleton means "dunce".

Comment: @TRomano - how then to call a less erudite man?

Comment: **the sophisticate** and **the average person** perhaps. *l'homme moyen sensuel*.

Comment: I don't think the use of **the** reflects confidence in an assumption; I think it's more of a semantic clarification, which some have called the **definite generic**.  We're not just talking about *any* intellectual, we're talking about the intellectual *as a type* who is reading "Foucault's Pendulum".  The "related posts" sidebar to this question actually include some pretty good discussions of this topic.

Comment: @standgon: You see no reinforcement whatsoever of the notion of the stereotype in the choice of determiner?

Comment: @TRomano - No, I actually do, but I think it's only because the author is referring to archetypes; I wouldn't want a reader to think, "Oh, 'the dog likes to eat garbage' is a more confident assertion than 'a dog likes to eat garbage'."

Comment: @standgon: I'll try to clarify. The phrases "*an* intellectual perusing" vs "*the* intellectual perusing" and "*a* simpleton absorbed in" vs "*the* simpleton absorbed in" are all examples of stereotyping (to call them *archetypes* is to hit outside the bullseye). The definite article makes the stereotyping *explicit* whereas the indefinite leaves it implicit; "the intellectual" refers to a *type* whereas "an intellectual" refers only to an *exemplar*. A speaker who states something explicitly is a tad more confident in the validity of the assertion than a speaker who leaves it up to inference.

Comment: "A speaker who states something explicitly is a tad more confident in the validity of the assertion than a speaker who leaves it up to inference" -- bullseye!

Answer (score 1):

*The intellectual* refers to the one and only prototype of the class *intellectual* and *an intellectual* refers to any member of the class *intellectual*.

---

You can **single out and point** to *the intellectual* because there is only one prototype in existence. When we point to an object, we can say *this* or *that*. Old English got along fine without a definite article, using the word for *that* (in its many inflections) as a marker of definiteness. (See Page 86 of *[a biography of the English language](https://books.google.com/books?id=nC4_1z292jUC&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22a+biography+of+the+english+language%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiepNiwncvKAhXGk4MKHTwfD1YQ6AEIHTAA#v=snippet&q=definiteness&f=false)*.)

You cannot do the same exact thing regarding *an intellectual* because he could be one/any of many. Sure you could point to *an intellectual* but there are others around that you could also point to and call *an intellectual*.

If it helps, you can think of *an intellectual* as *your average intellectual* or *any old intellectual*. See *Just give me one. I don't care which [one]* at *[any old thing](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/any+old+thing)*.

If it helps, both *[one](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=one)* and *[any](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=any)* are extremely close in etymology: *any* meaning *one-y*. See the Old English and, more to the point, proto-German words at those links.

In addition, **according to many scholars**, *one* used to be pronounced without the initial *w-* sound, so it sounded quite similar to unstressed *an*, which was the initial form of the indefinite article (later, folks dropped the *n* before consonants). This pronunciation, without initial *w-*, is retained in *only*.

Much of what I am writing here can apply to non-generic usages of *the* and *a*.

---

This question seems to follow your previous [“Only the masochist would choose to study Russian” or “Only a masochist would choose to study Russian”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/75865/only-the-masochist-would-choose-to-study-russian-or-only-a-masochist-would-ch). Yet as your average native speaker, I don't know why you would get this idea that you ask about here. Perhaps you could explain why you think this idea of yours might be true? What about three types of generic noun phrases (or two in this case) prompts this kind of idea?

Comment: The pronunciation bit is new to me. But I've read it in several academic  contexts. And, for instance, several puns in Shakespeare do not work if "one" is pronounced with initial *w-* sound. Plus, we (still) have the *w-less* pronunciation of "only" meaning "one-ly." But I have not read why the pronunciation of *one* would have changed to that of present-day English (PdE).

Comment: Thank you for the historical bit! I only wondered whether the two versions are completely interchangeable (to me, they seem interchangeable), and added a bit of musing to expand the question.

Comment: Since English has a definite article today, apparently Old English didn't "g[e]t along fine without a definite article".

Comment: @TRomano Old English did get along fine without one. Just like classical Latin did. Both areas where the languages were spoken were subject to conquest and upheaval, and the languages changed incredibly so as to become a different language (Middle English) or languages (Romance languages). The successors of both OE and Latin developed articles.